# bypassing the related field manager / referring alternate manager

Tags: python, django

My model (Lets say class "A") has two managers - the default one (objects), which hides some objects (applies a filter, let's say by a field hidden = models.BooleanField) and the second one, which shows only objects filtered by the default one (so applies opposite filter). So they are mutually exclusive.

I did this on purpose, because i don't want to involve these filtered objects anyhow in the admin interface.

So far, so good, it works. The problem i have is with related fields. I have a second model where i refer the first one (with these two managers) as ManyToMany field.

```
class B(models.Model):
    object_a = models.ManyToMany()
```

Now, in the logic i create some objects of the instance A with hidden = True (thus, invisible for the default objects manager of the class A). And i assign these objects to the instance of class B.

```
instance_b.object_a.add(instance_a.hidden_object_a)
```

Now, i thought it does not work, because instance_b.object_a.all() returns empty query result. But then i realised, that the default manager is also applied, so the query is filtered. And in fact, there are hidden objects assigned to the instance_b.object_a, they just cannot be returned by such a reference.
How can i refer them from withit the B instance? Or, how i can refer the other manager of the class A by referring through the ManyToMany field? Is it possible? Or i need a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it.
instance_b.object_a(manager='other_manager').all()